# My question is to write a python program to read 2 numbers from a file and write gcd and lcm of that 2 numbers to a second file.This is my code

Tags: python

```
with open ("source.txt","r") as file:

    line=file.readlines()
    a=line[0].strip()
    a=int(a)
    b=line[1].strip()
    b=int(b)

    def gcd(c,d):

        if d==0:
            return c
        else:
            return gcd(d,c%d)

e=gcd(a,b)
gcd=("GCD of", a,"and", b,"is",e)
Lcm=("LCM of", a,"and", b,"is",a*b//e)

with open ("Finaldes1.txt","w") as Finaldes:
    line1="{0}\n{1}".format(gcd,Lcm)
    linaldes.write(line1)
```

But when i open the the final file thae data is written within quotes like this 
('GCD of', 4, 'and', 6, 'is', 2)
('LCM of', 4, 'and', 6, 'is', 12).
I don't need this quotes at end and inbetween.What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you save tuples to your file. You can instead convert them to strings like this:

`gcd_string = " ".join(str(x) for x in gcd)`

and then save it like this:

`line1="{0}\n{1}".format(gcd_string,Lcm_string)`

or in the first place you can save them as strings

`gcd = "GCD of {0} and {1} is {2}".format(a, b, e)`

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
gcd=("GCD of %d and %d is %d" % (a, b, e))
Lcm=("LCM of %d and %d is %d" % (a*b//e))
```